# CancellationException occurs while subscribing to connectable hot source

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I am using reactor-core [3.1.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-core/3.1.4.RELEASE).

Consider the following code snippet:

```
Flux<String> flux = Flux.<String>create(sink -> sink.next("test"))
    .replay(1)
    .refCount();

flux.subscribe(System.out::println);
flux.next().subscribe(System.out::println); // The exception is thrown here!
```

Expected output:

```
test
test
```

Actual output:

```
test
Exception in thread "main" reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Disconnected
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Disconnected
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$ReplaySubscriber.dispose(FluxReplay.java:1202)
    at reactor.core.publisher.OperatorDisposables.dispose(OperatorDisposables.java:132)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRefCount$RefCountMonitor.innerCancelled(FluxRefCount.java:132)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRefCount$RefCountInner.cancel(FluxRefCount.java:200)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:75)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRefCount$RefCountInner.onNext(FluxRefCount.java:177)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replayNormal(FluxReplay.java:808)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replay(FluxReplay.java:892)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay.subscribe(FluxReplay.java:1085)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRefCount$RefCountMonitor.subscribe(FluxRefCount.java:116)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRefCount.subscribe(FluxRefCount.java:77)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3077)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:3185)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3071)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3038)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:2985)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

For me this is a bug in the reactor-core library. Is my statement correct or am I missing (misunderstanding) something?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was confirmed that this is a [bug](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1088). It is fixed in reactor-core [3.1.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.projectreactor/reactor-core/3.1.5.RELEASE).